# jQuery height paragraph ready event after altering text

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, load, ready

I'm having issues with fetching the size of a tag after altering the containing text. I currently have a solution that I'm far from satisfied with. This is what I have (*apologies for the coffeescript, ()=> means function(){})*

```
@textField = $('<'+tag+'></'+tag+'>')
@textField.html(text).delay(120).queue(()=>
    @textField.ready(@onTextReady)
)
```

If I remove the delay, there's no height(), I can't use window.load either, and @textfield.load seem to do absolutely nothing.

What are your thoughts on the best practice to solve this?

Much appreciated

/ A

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know elements don't have size until they are added to DOM. More than that I think there are issues with size and display none. If you are interested only in size and not in actually adding the element to DOM I suggest to play with visibility.

```
var $textField = $('<div>').text("FOO").css({
    visibility: "hidden",
    position: "absolute",
    display: "block"
}).appendTo($("body"));
var height = $textField.height();
$textField.remove();
alert(height);
```

Comment: I have my element in the DOM, sorry for not making it clearer

Comment: then it has to do with something you didn't post because my following code works just fine $("#textField").html("FOO"); alert($("#textField").height()); $("#textField").html("FOO<br/>FOO"); alert($("#textField").height());, giving me 19 and 38

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that a parent isn't 'added to the stage' do you think making a duplicate like you did and removing it is a good practice? just want to be certain

Comment: if you are interested in the size of the element, adding it to DOM is the only way therefore it has to be a good practice. Of course, hiding it can be obtained in various ways but I don;t think this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the single threaded nature of JavaScript and how HTML rendering is done by the browser. When you add an element to the DOM tree, this doesn't automatically mean that the renderer have drawn the element or calculated the element's properties etc.
You should add the element to the DOM tree, then **break** from the JavaScript thread, and put the code that access the element's properties in the queue so that its executed after the rendering.

```
element.appendChild(aChild); // Adding a child to the DOM tree    
setTimeout(function() {
    aChild.height;           // Accessing the height of the element
},0);                        // Setting the timeout to 0 so that the code
                             // is executed immediately
```

In fact, it's what you're doing in your approach. By adding a delay() and executing a callback after that timeout.

I Hope this gave you some more insights about this not so uncommon problem.